# Angular2: how to set component to show after ajax loading of data?

Tags: angular

I have a div where I want to show some content:

```
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

the route is defined here:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent},
];
```

Immediately after entering the URL the details-component is shown
details.component.html:

```
<p>loading...</p>
```

details.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
        .params
        .subscribe(params => {
            this.load(params['id']);
        });
}
```

After loading is done (this.load), I want to show a different component. Which one depends on the loaded data. This component will contain a form. Furthermore I want to reset the form every time a load is performed, e.g. by clicking a reload button.

So I am looking for a call to tell angular: put component X into router-outlet Y now. Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a combination of Observable and ngIf you can subscribe to an Observable and have a function to display or not a subsection of your view according to the results of your fetched data.

Lets suppose your component initially displays a Loading... screen when no data is present.

#### Loading...

so in your html you can have:

```
<span *ngIf="busy">
  <h3>Loading...</h3>
</span>

<div *ngIf="!busy">
  <a *ngFor="let user of (users$ | async)">
      <img src="{{user.img}}" alt="{{user.name}}">
  </a>
</div>
```

And in your componenent:

```
   @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'sd-user',
      templateUrl: 'user.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['user.component.css']
    })
    export class UserComponent {
      public users$: Observable<User>;
      private busy:boolean;

      constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>, public routerext: RouterExtensions) {
        this.busy = true;
        // returns observable
        this.users$ = store.let(getUsers);    

        this.users$.subscribe(
          (x) => { // next
            console.log('Next ' + x);
            this.busy = false;
          },
          (err) => { // error
          console.log('Error: ' + err);
            this.busy = false;        
          },
          () => { // completed
            console.log('Completed');
            this.busy = false;
          }      
        );        
      }
  // ... whenever you dispatch a new action that will trigger a server 
// side call you should set this.busy to true and reset your form if needed.
}
```